# Connect Python with MySQL using MySQLdb or connector in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, ubuntu-18.04

I can't connect MySQL using MySQLdb in Ubuntu 18.04.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

This code is showing internal server error.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you either installed MySQLdb using pip or maybe installed a MySQLdb package that is not compatible with Python 2.x which is not installed by default in Ubuntu 18.04.

Install python-mysqldb from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python2.7 python-mysqldb
```

Then `import MySQLdb` will work correctly.

Comment: @NazirMallick If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.